# Compiled Azure Function Monitoring: "No data available"

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm using a couple of compiled C# functions on Azure. They are working as expected, but when I click 'Monitor' on either of the functions, it just shows up "No data available".

I can see the function running on the 'Develop' tab's log, but would like an overview of the function's usage.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Your logs are stored in Storage. Can you look at your App Settings and confirm you have a AzureWebJobsDashboard app setting set up? Could you share an invocation id (and region if you can) from one of your runs you see in the streaming logs?

Comment: Also, are you using app service authentication? Are there any errors in the browser console when you click on the monitor tab or requests that return unexpected results (404, etc)?

Comment: I have a similar issue. Instead of "No Data Available", my Monitor page is only showing function invocation logs from 11 days ago, even though the function has been run as recent as 2 days ago. Confirmed that I have the AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage env variables set, (they happen to be using the same connection string). In my Kudu page, the function invocation log there shows the recent executions from 2 days ago. In my Table Storage, I do see rows with a StartTime matching for 2 days ago.  ID of function executed now: 85109356-dfe4-47cf-a982-a9f26d9f4503, no update in Monitor

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT  - any ideas what the problem may be? Is it a configuration issue on our side? This has our production ops people very concerned that they can't use Monitoring page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We believe we have found an issue when explicit host ids are set in the host file, which is what is likely causing the problem.

We're tracking this issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1393) and will update it as we make progress.

As a workaround, please remove the id from your host.json file.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. The host.json file is empty ("{}"). Compiled functions are working, and I can see the logs on the Develop tab, but Monitor doesn't work. No errors, just nothing or old data.

Comment: Update: I think I fixed it, see my answer to this post. Somehow the "AzureWebJobsHostLogscommon" table was missing one of the functions, which broke the Monitor tab for all of them.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. Despite my code having an empty host.json file, the deployed functions app had an id in the file. Having removed the id and restarted the functions app, my issue is now gone.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing these too. I compared a function app that is working with one that isn't working. The one that isn't working returns a 404 when I click "refresh" in the monitor tab. It's hitting an URL like this:

`https://[YOUR_APP].scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/api/functions/definitions//invocations?limit=20`

Note the double slashes before "invocations".

In a working app, it's more like:

`https://[YOUR_APP].scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/api/functions/definitions/[YOUR_APP]-[YOUR_FUNCTION]/invocations?limit=20`

So something has happened to blow up the `[YOUR_APP]-[YOUR_FUNCTION]` part of the URL that the portal generates. Any ideas?

--

**UPDATE:** I think I fixed it.

I connected to the storage account associated with the function app using Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer. When I went to Tables > AzureWebJobsHostLogscommon, I noticed two things:

- there was an entry for a function I had deleted
- there was a function that I had created that had no entry (well, it existed in the "default-[YOUR_FUNCTION]" RowKey, but the "[YOUR_APP]-[YOUR_FUNCTION]" RowKey was missing

I added a new row for the missing "[YOUR_APP]-[YOUR_FUNCTION]" RowKey and set the OriginalName to the real function name. I went back to the portal, and poof! it started working.

I didn't bother deleting the extraneous entry from the deleted function. It didn't seem to hurt anything. But if any real function is missing, it seems to break the whole Monitor tab.

How it got that way, I'm not sure. Maybe it was doing something when I published an update.

--

**UPDATE 2**: Well, that got the Monitor tab working, but the data is "stale", as if someone background process isn't refreshing. I can see the log data appearing in Table Storage...

--

**UPDATE 3**: The stale data seems to be separate issue in the East US region, tracked at https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/259 ... the "no data available" issue I think was fixed by me correcting the `AzureWebJobsHostLogscommon` table as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the "No data available" problem. I solved it by adding an application setting that was missing: `"FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~1"`

Reference, David Ebbo comment on GitHub:
https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/259#issuecomment-300379674

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, resolved it by emptying the host.json and making
`"FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~3"`