# Precompiled Azure function doesn't seem to be invoked

Tags: azure-functions

I have migrated some webhook handlers to the new pre-compiled project format and published them.

I have tried to get monitoring and logging working without success.

I have removed the auto-generated attribute from function.json, and there are no hard-coded host id in host.json as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277013/compiled-azure-function-monitoring-no-data-available)

No errors or any other logging that I can see. Any suggestions?

It doesn't seem possible to remotely debug these yet either as mentioned in the comments [here](http://markheath.net/post/remote-debugging-azure-functions)

**EDIT:**

Here is the webhook info when configured to send a GET to requestbin: https://requestb.in/148h5n31?inspect

**EDIT 2:**

Reviewing KUDU shows some errors in the detailedtrace logs, but not at the time when I submit requests:

HTTP Error 412.0 - Precondition: Failed: https://~1<>:80/dev/server.js

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found: https://~1<>:80/dev/server.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stumbled across the reason. Don't think its do with the fact that the function is precompiled.

The problem is that I was using the URL listed under the Function App Settings tab.

The actual URL is that URL + '/api/' +  the function name attribute you define in your function.

e.g.

```
 [FunctionName("Foobar")]
```

The specific function URL can be found from the link which says `</> Get function URL`. Here is a screenshot:

[image]